# jquery datepicker - how to make readonly and required?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-validate

I am creating a form, the customer has requested an 'eventStart' and 'eventStop' range, they also want it to be required, and don't want anyone to be able to manually change the values.

I am using jquery datePicker and jquery validate.

I have it working one way or the other, but not both.

```
<input class="inputs" type="text" id="eventStart"  readonly/>
<input class="inputs" type="text" id="eventStop"  readonly/>
```

This works perfectly, the range works, and it cannot be manually edited.

```
<input class="inputs" type="text" id="eventStart"  required/>
<input class="inputs" type="text" id="eventStop"  required/>
```

This pops up the "! Please fill out this field", but allows the date to be manually edited.

If I put both, it allows the user to skip the field (no validation.)

Comment: I guess I don't understand the need for required and read only on the same object, why have it all?

Comment: Data input validation ensures that the user enters the correct data.  If it's `readonly`, then there is no need for input validation at all.

Comment: Agreed. Assuming some JS code is pre-filling the datepicker, why do you want to add validation to it if the user can't change it anyway?

Comment: **If the pop-up really says _"please fill out this field"_, then you are NOT using the jQuery Validate plugin**... it's broken or not installed properly.  _"please fill out this field"_ is HTML 5 validation coming from the browser.  Plus, by default, the jQuery Validation plugin does not create pop-ups... again, that's HTML 5 validation from the browser.  When the jQuery Validate plugin is working properly, it dynamically _disables_ HTML 5 validation so it can take over.

Comment: Show enough code to make a working demo of your form including your jQuery Validate setup and HTML markup.  Also, please address the first three comments regarding why you would need validation on a field that's already populated by code and cannot be changed by the user.  After all, what if this `readonly` field fails validation... what is the user supposed to do about this if he cannot edit?

Comment: The data is input using the calendar that pops up. The readonly makes it so it can't be changed with the keyboard in the input box, thus bypassing the range.

Comment: Sparky - I didn't think of the jquery validate plugin not working, I will check it out - thanks.

Comment: Sparky - I removed the validate plugin, the built in validation works good enough for this application. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case if you add readonly and required and it bypasses validation your options are to implement your own validation or to hook form submit or the onclick action of your submit button.

Another option is to use required only. Then hook the keydown action and stop text entry.

```
$("#inputs").keydown(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This will only stop text entry and is not secure. Sneaky people can still change the value if they want. Don't forget to validate field entry on the backend.

Comment: The point is to attain the requests that a client has bestowed. Not to  mention the issue on mobile where if you try to use a datepicker on a field the keyboard will popup. The only way to fix that is to set readonly.

Comment: The OP has bigger problems as he's confusing HTML 5 validation bubbles with the jQuery Validation plugin, which is not even working.

Comment: That is true. However, you asked what's the point. I gave you a point, and this is a valid solution to the question he asked.

Comment: And my second comment has nothing to do with my first comment... it's a new point (he needs to get the plugin working before he can think about your answer).  I'm not 100% convinced this is the correct answer, but if I thought it was a bad answer, I would have already down-voted it.

Comment: Sparky was correct, I was confusing the validate plugin, so I removed it. I implemented James McDonnell's answer, and this does exactly what I needed. (Is there a way to allow only the tab key?)

Comment: You can check for the key code with `event.keyCode`. It returns a value that corresponds to the key you pressed.

Answer (score 0):

i have this workaround
`$nextmonth = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59',strtotime("+1 month"));`
and for input
`<input type="text" class="text-input" name="project_deadline" id="project_deadline" value="<?php echo $nextmonth ?>" readonly />`